# How to play NSData from Core Data in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, avaudioplayer

I save mp3 file into Core Data as NSData binary data. Then I load this file with help of `NSFetchedResultsController`. Then I wrote following code but I got the error. How can I fix it?

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
func play() {
    if musicData != nil {
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: musicData, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I checked it and I saw that `AVAudioPlayer` is nil but I init this player in beginning of this class.

Still I changed code but I get the same error
The second method

```
var av = AVAudioPlayer()
func play() {
    let object = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.first as! Entity
    let songData = object.mp3

    var urlData: NSURL!
    songData.writeToURL(urlData, atomically: true)
    av = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: urlData, error: nil)
    av.prepareToPlay()
    av.play()
}
```

Comment: Which line of code causes the error? It sounds like you might not be reading the binary data - or rather, the data might not have been saved?

Comment: Data have been saved I checked it. I println it in console and I get binary code. Here is error in audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: musicData, error: nil)

Comment: The issue is that your error message refers to unwrapping an optional but the code that you have supplied doesn't *appear* to contain any optionals. Have you set a breakpoint on exceptions so that you can see which line of code causes the error?

Comment: If your data is invalid in any way then `AVAudioPlayer(data: error:)` will return nil.

Comment: Error on this line  audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: musicData, error: &error), but if I print musicData( NSData) console shows this code 681fe8ec e128b614 74587062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the file type hint and it works for me.

```
  func playMusic() {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: data, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with playing mp3 file from Core Data. There is another solution, which don't require you to make resources, but only file manager . Works in Swift 5:

```swift
final class AudioPlayer: AVPlayer, ObservableObject {

    private func changeSong(with newSong: Song) { // struct Song has function findInDatabase, which can return saved data from CoreData (or error)

        // trying to find song in CoreData
        newSong.findInDatabase() { (result: Result<SavedSong, CoreDataError>) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let savedSong):
                // SavedSong struct has variable 'file' which is of type Data
                guard let songFile = savedSong.file, !songFile.isEmpty else {
                    // your error handling
                    return
                }

                guard var localURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return } // or error handling
                localURL.appendPathComponent("song.mp3")
                try! songFile.write(to: localURL) // saving song data in url

                // now just playing from created URL
                let nextPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: localURL)
                self.replaceCurrentItem(with: nextPlayerItem) // 'self' - is AVPlayer instance
                self.play()

            case .failure( _):
                // error handling, for example try to play from URL
            }

        }

    } 

}
```